# How to skip null filters for countunique in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with 5 columns and I use the 4 columns' values as filters. Sometimes any (or all) of the filters can be null.
Table example:

| ID | Company | Month | Revenue | Returns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sams | 1 | 1000 | 50 |
| 2 | Amaz | 1 | 10000 | 100 |
| 3 | Goog | 2 | 5000 | 200 |
| 4 | Amaz | 3 | 2000 | 10 |
| 5 | Micro | 3 | 1000 | 50 |

How can I utilize a query like:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,DATA!C2:C=B3,DATA!D2:D>=B4,DATA!E2:E<B5)
```

And if e.g. B3 is null to ignore that condition and utilize the rest filters for the countunique? I feel that there must be a more efficient way than coding for each scenario with ifs.

Comment: add `,DATA!B2:B<>""` to the criteria of the filter

Comment: Apologies, I mean that when B3 is null to skip the part DATA!C2:C=B3 and only use the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea.
You can sort of "override" that condition in your FILTER by raising the whole condition "array" to the 0 power if B3 is empty.  Since any value to the 0 power is 1.

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,(DATA!C2:C=B3)^(B3<>""),DATA!D2:D>=B4,DATA!E2:E<B5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always difficult to suggest a formula when we don't actually have access to the data in order to test the formula (sort of like a mechanic trying to diagnose an unseen car over the phone). But you can try this:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(B2:B,DATA!C2:C=IF(B3<>"",B3,DATA!C2:C),DATA!D2:D>=IF(B4<>"",B4,DATA!D2:D),DATA!E2:E<IF(B5<>"",B5,DATA!E2:E+1))))`

In theory, it should work as you expect. Please report back as to whether or not that is true, and I will add an explanation for how it works. In the interest of efficiency, I don't want to put the cart before the horse.

Comment: If the above formula suggestion *does not* produce the result you expect, please share a link to your sheet (or to a copy of your sheet), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."